# Storage Agnostic Options for Querying Read Models

Tags: nservicebus, cqrs

When using CQRS and Event Sourcing - I am wondering what my options are for agnostically querying my read models if they are built by a remote event handler instead of inside my presentation project.

I am using NServiceBus to send commands and publish events, and I've configured an application project to listen to events and build read models in RavenDB.

I would have my presentation project read from RavenDB, but that locks my presentation layer into using RavenDB or anything else my event listeners use and I would like to keep the presentation layer agnostic.

I was originally thinking about using NServiceBus request/response, but various things I've read warm against this.

Are there any options for this?

**Edit From Comments**

What I am doing is building read models in ravendb using a separate running process to listen for events and save results.
The only options I have found to retrieve the results of these built models is to have my presentation object (aka web api) connect to ravendb.  This is what I am trying to avoid.

*why?*

Well if I want to spin up 20 instances of my web api to balance requests, each instance would have to connect to ravendb - in addition to the many read model building processes I already have connected.  Making ravendb the bottleneck.

Ideally what I would want to do is send a request from my web api to the application queue for data, and wait for the data to come back in the form of a reply.  This way I don't care at all about what my application processes are doing or how they store data, I just get data.

There are 2 articles I've read about this approach -

This one says don't do it
http://andreasohlund.net/2010/04/22/messaging-shouldnt-be-used-for-queries/

This one says go for it
http://www.udidahan.com/2007/11/10/asynchronous-high-performance-login-for-web-farms/

Comment: You can use Query Handlers or the good old Repository (not the DDD one)

Comment: Thanks, repository is just a mask over a fixed data source - I've had to migrate data sources keeping the same repo and its never as easy as the hype says.  All the examples I find for query handlers boil down to a repo and on-server query data access.  Perhaps you can provide an example of using a message based query handler?

Comment: First of all, a proper Repository pattern ONLY works with app objects in your case view models, so you can really switch data sources when you wanted, ofc you need a totally different repo implementation as well. Query handlers sit directly in DAL querying the data source. They too return view models and need to be rewritten for a different data source. But in both cases, the presentation layer is decoupled from persistence and that's what you wanted

Comment: I do like the idea of query handlers, its something I was not aware of - but what I would REALLY like is someway to not have my presentation process accessing a DB at all.  Perhaps a little greedy.

Comment: @Charles you mean your read models not even accessing the repositories?

Comment: @Charles Query Handlers are implemented in DAL (like a repository) the presentation knows only about IQUery<Input,Output> and even that can be hidden if you wanted.

Comment: I've updated my question with further detail - thanks for the comments so far guys they help

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing it right, you're choosing a read model that's extremely well focused to the read task you have at hand. Unless you think you're going to swap it out, just use the product directly! Go against a simple SQL interface (e.g. jdbc, ado.net) for a relational read model. Use Cypher for a graph model. Use a native API for a key-value store. Don't add yet another abstraction; that's much of the purpose of separating reads and writes in the first place.

Comment: That's a good point - only the presentation object will know exactly what read information he'll need and he should only get exactly what he needs